# How to match user input with arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

```
package BankingSystem;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Bank {

  public static void main(String [] args){

      List<String> AccountList = new ArrayList<String>(); 
      AccountList.add("45678690");
      Scanner AccountInput = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Hi whats your pin code?");
      AccountInput.nextLine();

      for  (int counter = 0; counter < AccountList.size(); counter++){  
          if (AccountInput.equals(AccountList.get(counter))){ //If Input = ArrayList number then display "hi"
              System.out.println("Hi");

          }
          else { //If not = to ArrayList then display "Incorrect"
              System.out.println("Incorrect");

          }
          }
      }
      }
```

Hi, in here I am trying to match the userInput to arrayList, if its correct then display "hi" if not display "Incorrect", for the incorrect part do I to use exception handling? and how can I get it to match the ArrayList number - 45678690?

Comment: Where did you store AccountInput.nextLine();  ?

Comment: before the for loop? should it be after or?

Comment: [Scanner.nextLine()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine())

Comment: AccountInput.nextLine() fetches the next line right? where is the variable to store that line? you want to call .equals() on that string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to store the input value in a string to check the number :

```
String value = AccountInput.nextLine();
if (value.equals(AccountList.get(counter))) ...
```

Answer (score 1):

First things first you need to store your user's input into some string as you currently aren't doing that.

Instead of using a counter and iterating through your list you can instead just use

```
AccountList.contains(the string variable assigned to AccountInput)
```

If it's false then the entry isn't there, otherwise it's in there. The exception handling you might want to use in this scenario would be to handle a user inputting letters instead of numbers.

Answer (score 1):

.nextLine() returns a string which needs to be assigned to a variable ....
And then compare the variable with elements in the arraylist using .contains() method ...
If you also want the index position use .indexOf() method ...

```
String input = AccountInput.nextLine();
if(AccountList.contains(input))
      // do something
else
      // do something else
```

Answer (score 0):

Start variables with lower case. Names that start with upper case is for Classes only in java. So use `List<String> accountList` , and not `List<String> AccountList` .

The main problem in your code is that you are comparing the elements in list with the Scanner-object. And that will always be false.
You also never store the input from the Scanner any place.
You need to place the return value somewhere, like

```
String input = scanner.nextLine();
```

and compare the strings in the list to this string, not the Scanner-object.

I've added a flag so that it works correctly with multiple items in the accountList.

```
List<String> accountList = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    accountList.add("45678690");
    accountList.add("1");
    accountList.add("0");

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Hi whats your pin code?");
    String accountInput = scanner.nextLine();

    boolean listContainsInput = false;
    for  (int counter = 0; counter < accountList.size(); counter++){  
        if (accountInput.equals(accountList.get(counter))){
            listContainsInput = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(listContainsInput) {
        System.out.println("Hi");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Incorrect");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing the instance of the Class Scanner

```
Scanner AccountInput = new Scanner(System.in);
```

To a String:

```
AccountInput.equals(AccountList.get(counter))
```

(ArrayList.get(int) returns a String or fires an Exception)

You need to start with comparing String to String first:

```
AccountInput.nextLine().equals(AccountList.get(counter))
```

If you need additional debbuging see how both strings look like(e.q. print 'em)

Here is documentation on Scanner:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html
Read it, scanner is important thing in programming languages.